# How to position images and text inside divs?

Tags: html, css

I am making a ten-page website and I made the general layout but I can't figure out how to position images and text in the div box. Nothing works. In this particular page I want the image to be on the top right of the Div and the text to be on the left. I feel if I can get the general idea of how this works I will be able to do it for the other pages as well.

Below is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    
        <html>
    
    
    
        <style>
        h1{
           color:white;
           font-size: 50px;
           font-family: ultra;
        }
    
        p{
        color:white;
        }
    
        h2{
        color:white;
        }
    
        body {
            font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
        }
    
    
    
        .sidenav {
            height: 100%;
            width: 250px;
            position: fixed;
            z-index: 1;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            background-color: red;
            overflow-x: hidden;
            padding-top: 60px;
        }
    
        .sidenav a {
            padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-size: 25px;
            color: black;
            display: block;
        }
    
        .sidenav a:hover {
            color: #818181;
       }
    
        .main {
            margin-left: 250px; 
            font-size: 28px; 
     
        }
    
    @media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
        .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
        .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
    }
    
    
    body {
     
     background-color:#252525;
     background-attachment:fixed;
     background-position: 50% 50%;
     background-repeat:no-repeat;
    
    
    
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    
    
    .header {
        background-color: #252525;
        padding: 10px;
        margin-left: 250px;
        text-align: center;
    }
    
    
    
    
    
    .rcorners1 {
        margin: auto;
        
        border-radius: 25px;
        background: #73AD21;
        padding: 20px;
        width: 90%;
        height: 1000px;
    
     
     
    
    
    </style>
    
    
    <body>
    
    <div class="sidenav">
    <a href="home.html">Home</a>
    <a href="about.html">About</a>
    <a href="Why Us.html">Why Us?</a>
    <a href="Meet The Team.html">Meet The Team</a>
    <a href="Gear.html">Gear</a>
    <a href="Services.html">Services</a>
    <a href="Products.html">Products</a>
    <a href="Satisfied Customers.html">Reviews</a>
    <a href="Location.html">Location</a>
    <a href="Contact Us.html">Contact Us</a>
    </div>
    
    
    
    
    <div class="header">
      <h1>GEAR</h1>
    </div>
    
    
    <div align="center">
    <div class="main">
        <div class="rcorners1" style="background-color: #fffafa;" "text-align:right;"> 
        <img src="Our Gadgets.jpg" class="expand" width="400" height="391" alt=""/> 
        <div>Content for New Div Tag Goes Here</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve what you are looking for, with `float: right` property. Try this code.

```css
h1{
     color:white;
     font-size: 50px;
     font-family: ultra;
}
 p{
     color:white;
}
 h2{
     color:white;
}
 body {
     font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}
 .sidenav {
     height: 100%;
     width: 250px;
     position: fixed;
     z-index: 1;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     background-color: red;
     overflow-x: hidden;
     padding-top: 60px;
}
 .sidenav a {
     padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
     text-decoration: none;
     font-size: 25px;
     color: black;
     display: block;
}
 .sidenav a:hover {
     color: #818181;
}
 .main {
     margin-left: 250px;
     font-size: 28px;
}
 @media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
     .sidenav {
        padding-top: 15px;
    }
     .sidenav a {
        font-size: 18px;
    }
}
 body {
     background-color:#252525;
     background-attachment:fixed;
     background-position: 50% 50%;
     background-repeat:no-repeat;
     margin: 0;
}
 .header {
     background-color: #252525;
     padding: 10px;
     margin-left: 250px;
     text-align: center;
}
 .rcorners1 {
     margin: auto;
     border-radius: 25px;
     background: #73AD21;
     padding: 20px;
     width: 90%;
     height: 1000px;
}
 .main img {
     float: right;
     margin-left: 10px;
}
 .clear {
     clear: both;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <body>
      <div class="sidenav">
         <a href="home.html">Home</a>
         <a href="about.html">About</a>
         <a href="Why Us.html">Why Us?</a>
         <a href="Meet The Team.html">Meet The Team</a>
         <a href="Gear.html">Gear</a>
         <a href="Services.html">Services</a>
         <a href="Products.html">Products</a>
         <a href="Satisfied Customers.html">Reviews</a>
         <a href="Location.html">Location</a>
         <a href="Contact Us.html">Contact Us</a>
      </div>
      <div class="header">
         <h1>GEAR</h1>
      </div>
      <div align="center">
         <div class="main">
            <div class="rcorners1" style="background-color: #fffafa;" "text-align:right;"> 
            <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300" class="expand" width="100" height="100" alt=""/> 
            <div class="text">Content for New Div Tag Goes Here</div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: How would I vertically align the text beside the image?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is wrongly finished, look at the below sample from your code, put another `</div>` tag.

```
<div align="center">
<div class="main">
    <div class="rcorners1" style="background-color: #fffafa;" "text-align:right;"> 
    <img src="Our Gadgets.jpg" class="expand" width="400" height="391" alt=""/> 
    <div>Content for New Div Tag Goes Here</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

if you place image on the top right and text on the left,  then simple use bootstrap for making grids like `.col-md-6 .col-sm-12 .col-xs-12` in both image and text

**OR**

if you wrap the text around the image, then use `float: right` on the image and it will move to te right and text will wrap the image.

By the way, the code looks so messy, Don't put styles inside HTML page, use an external stylesheet for that.

Comment: This is my test page where I test all the style elements before making a style sheet my other pages do have a stylesheet also thank your for your help.

Comment: Does this right and left works? if anything not working, comment here...
I also edit your question, please look at the changes and approve that edit.